# Does Node on Ubuntu use a different user/role?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

My Node app cannot see `$PATH` changes.

What I did:

1. ssh onto a remote server as user `ubuntu`
2. modified `.bash_profile` by adding a $PATH: `export PATH=$PATH:~/`, then `source` to apply the new change.
3. In the node app running on the server, I used [node-cmd](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cmd) to run a `sh` script to log out $PATH
4. The logged path does not contain my new changes.

So why the node app is seeing a different $PATH, does it use a different user/role?

Comment: have You restarted running nodejs app after change on `.bash_profile`?

Comment: `node-cmd` does not source the `.bash_profile`. Why should it?

Comment: @RaphaMex I think he has running app that executes command using node-cmd package. He changed environment variable, called source .bash_profile, but not restarted nodejs app. Environmental variables cannot be dynamically modified externally, cuz it may crash app when sudden change. So that's why it gets environmental variables to `process.env` on application start and to update it You've to restart the app, or figure out getting such variables from database or nosql storage that can be modified externally.

Comment: @num8er I only restarted `pm2` which manages the node app, which didn't help

Comment: Could You just for experiment do: console.log(process.env) in Your code and execute it manually. And it will show that it has changes to do pm2 kill and then pm2 start your app?

Comment: Also check this one: `require('os').homedir()`

Comment: @RaphaMex I thought my previous `source` has made changes to the ubuntu environment so `node-cmd` doesn't need to do it again, is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If You want to get the path to current user's home dir just use `os` module.

> os.homedir()#
>
> Added in: v2.3.0
>
> Returns:
>
> The os.homedir() method returns the home directory of the current user
>   as a string.

Usage:

```
const homedir = require('os').homedir();
process.env.PATH = homedir;
```

P.S. I don't see any reason to use node-cmd when You can use `child_process` module's `exec`, `execFile`, `spawn` and etc. that can take options where You can pass additional variables.

Comment: Thanks for the alternative method!